# Twitter Bootstrap text field's height too small?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap and i find the height of the text field is too small.It's like less than 10px.I am wondering if it is small or i made some mistakes.

I used firebug to inspect the text area.It says the height is 18px,which seems impossible for me...And what i got is the same as i got from here.[Text area from bootstrap example](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms).It makes me rather confused...
what i got is

```
input, textarea, select, .uneditable-input {
  border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
  color: #555555;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 13px;
  height: 18px;
  line-height: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 9px;
  padding: 4px;
}
```

The height says it's 18px, but it's not...
Can somebody help?!

Comment: OK.I find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170305/twitters-bootstrap-form-inputs-too-thin) helped.But I would be glad if anyone can explain this to me.It seems pretty weird that css properties are exact the same but the outcome is so different...What the !DOCTYPE part has to do with css?!

Comment: The DOCTYPE determines how lenient a browser will be when rendering a page. Check out http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html for some examples.

Comment: I read that but I can't figure out which part would go wrong if i don't set DOCTYPE :P...confused still...

Comment: @SomeshMukherjee nope,it didn't work...

Comment: what is the height then?

Comment: possible duplicate of [text input rendering issue with twitter bootstrap.css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7196398/text-input-rendering-issue-with-twitter-bootstrap-css)

Answer (score 167, accepted):

Adding `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` should fix this. The same question was asked here: [Text input rendering issue with Twitter Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7196398/text-input-rendering-issue-with-twitter-bootstrap-css)

Comment: Yes.I found a similar question too.I posted it on the comment area above.I should have ended this question.But I didn't figure out why it fixed the problem though.

Comment: Fixed it for me! But why? :)

Comment: i just spend ed over 2 hours to get this fixed,because the icons didn't matched the text fields.By accident deleted the doctype. +1...THANKS!!

Comment: I think it has something to do with quirks mode. If you accidentally leave out the doctype or use a misformatted doctype, it will activate quirks mode and give you weird results. http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html and http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/

Comment: I have <!DOCTYPE HTML> in my document, and this does not fix the issue :\

Comment: Was about to write my input text css before I find this. Thanks :)

Comment: lol, take me a day for such simple solution like this, been searching through css but not found  :D

Answer (score 7):

**Incase the top answer didn't help**

I had `<!DOCTYPE html>` already and it wasn't the problem for me. I don't know what is the problem, but
I fixed it with this in my css:

```
input[type=text], input[type=password], input[type=email], input[type=tel] {
    height: 28px !important;
}
```

It's a workaround and I'm not sure if it has some side effects.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why if I open a clean new HTML5 page it works but after I add some code I don't know why it happens. So I just open the bootstrap.min.css file and search:`type="text"` and there there is height property and I change it to min-height for it have to be working.

Answer (score 2):

Yes the total `height` is `28px` because padding & border also add `height` to that `input` like this:

```
height 18px + 
4px padding-top + 
4px padding-bottom + 
1px border-top + 
1px border-bottom = 
Total 28px height
```

Answer (score 2):

See my solution here [in a similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11197432/1481102).

Basically, the text file encoding was causing all my trouble. It manifested in such minute differences across browsers that I wasted hours fiddling with CSS thinking that was the cause.

Comment: You are right nothing to do with CSS. I had the same problem with one of my php files being encoded in utf8 instead of ascii.