# text field too narrow vertically with bootstrap/rails

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-3.2, railstutorial.org

I'm working through the rails tutorial and I noticed a little bit into the application that the height of my textarea is rendering smaller than it was earlier.

I've looked through this [thread here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7196398/text-input-rendering-issue-with-twitter-bootstrap-css) and [this one as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9222851/twitter-bootstrap-text-fields-height-too-small?rq=1), both essentially suggesting that the error commonly stems from not having `<!DOCTYPE HTML>`. However, as you'll see in my [first screenshot](http://cl.ly/image/2O1E2R3g1j0I), that's not the case for me.

In the first screenshot, you can see that when I highlight the element, it suggests that it knows it should be rendering at a thicker size, but for whatever reason it isn't. [Here's what the text area should look like](http://cl.ly/image/172b2Z193t3i) (taken from the bootstrap documentation).

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

**edit:**
Here's the code for the view:

```
<% provide(:title, "Sign in") %>
<h1>Sign in</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="span6 offset3">
     <%= form_for(:session, url: sessions_path) do |f| %>

        <%= f.label :email %>
        <%= f.text_field :email %>

        <%= f.label :password %>
        <%= f.password_field :password %>

        <%= f.submit "Sign in", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
     <% end %>
     <p>New user? <%= link_to "Sign up now!", signup_path %></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I might be misunderstanding, but make sure you're using text_area and not text_field if you want a multi line input. You can then provide a `rows => 10` argument to define how tall the area is, this is also commonly controlled with a CSS height attribute. Can you post your view code?

Comment: Just added it. Sorry if I wasn't specific enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add bootstrap class in to your text_field tag as

```
 <%= f.text_field :email,:class=> 'input-xlarge' %>
```

this might be helpful